# Cannot call animation function inside and onclick function

Tags: javascript

So the problem I am having here is that *function frame()* will not call inside *function HideLogin()* I am getting an error in the console:

Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at frame (page1.js:46)

Which im sure one can see that i have defined the function in HideLogin inwhich then i proceed to send it as an argument.
The function is supposed to move Sign Up text up with an animation onclick. This works fine when I put the whole frame function inside HideLogin. but for some reason I cannot invoke it as I would like too. How can I call frame inside of HideLogin? Thanx in advance

Javascript

```
function HideLogin()
{
    var login = document.getElementById("login");
    var SignUpSheet = document.getElementById("SignUpSheet");
    var titlecard = document.getElementById("titlecard");

    var signup = document.getElementById("signup");
    var pos = 125;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);

    login.style.display = "none";
    SignUpSheet.style.display = "block";
    titlecard.style.display = "block";

    frame(signup, pos, id);

}

function frame(signin, pos, id) 
{
    if (pos == 0) {
    clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        pos--; 
        signup.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    }
}
```

CSS

```
       #signup /* sign up link */
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            //border: 2px solid white;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            top: 125px;
            font-family: papyrus;
            font-size: 70px; 
            color: red;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
            transition: text-shadow 0.5s ease;
        }

            #signup:hover
            {
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, black);
                -webkit-background-clip: text;
                -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
                text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
            }
```

HTML

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Prime Legion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page1.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="page1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logBox">
        <div id="login" onclick="HideSignin()">
            Log In
        </div>
        <div id="signup" onclick="HideLogin()">
            Sign Up
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="LogInSheet">
        <div id="LoginTitle">
            <p><h4>Hello</h4></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="SignUpSheet">
        <div id="SignupTitle">
            <p><h4>Welcome</h4></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="titlecard">
        <p><h1>The Prime Legion</h1></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `signup.style.top = pos + 'px'` to `signin.style.top = pos + 'px'`;

Comment: I figured it out. I had to assign a set interval function to id in order to make this work correctly. but you where a good step in solving this issue. Thanx to you and to all.

Answer (score 0):

Change Parameter name from `signin` to `signup`. You are trying to use the variable `signin` which is not defined in the `frame` function, neither is the variable `signin` a global variable. So the variable `signup` is undefined and hence you are getting the error

> "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at frame"

`function frame(signin, pos, id)`

to

`function frame(signup, pos, id)`

```
function frame(signup, pos, id) 
{
    if (pos == 0) {
    clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        pos--; 
        signup.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not forget to mark answer as helpful